# Error 401 while trying to connect to TFSAPI

Tags: python, tfs

I'm trying to create connection to tfs using python TFSAPI,
the tfs is local "http://***.**.**.**:8080/tfs/default_Collection/Default
and i'm getting this error
**requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:**
the credentials are right, they work for simple login
tried this:

```
from tfs import TFSAPI
client = TFSAPI(path, user = user, password = password)
workitem = client.get_workitem(100) # Test connection with Workitem id
```

then like this

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
username = ' '
password = " "
tfsApi = path
tfsResponse = requests.get(tfsApi,auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username,password))
```

both end up with same error
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\ohad-ar\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:**
any suggestions are welcomed, including a different way to connect tfs api using python
Thanks very much

Comment: it worked with personal access token, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tfs import TFSAPI
personalAccessToken = "privetPersonalAccessToken"
path = "http://111.11.11.11:8080/tfs/HRCM_Collection/"
client = TFSAPI(path, pat=personalAccessToken ,project = "DefaultProject")
workitemId = 130000
workitem = client.get_workitem(workitemId )
```

this worked for me,
to get the personal access token use
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page